# How to remove a valueless query string parameter in C#

Tags: c#, query-string

Given a requested url:

> myite.com/en/?ncr

How does one remove the query string paramter by name, without reducing to simple string operation by hand?

```
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(curUri.Query);
queryString.Remove("ncr");
```

wouldn't work, since ?ncr has no value set.

P.S. 
After parsing, variable query string still contains valueless parameters, which are "checkable" via

```
queryString.GetValues(null).Contains("ncr")
```

which would return true for a given request string.

Comment: Either `ncr` is present in `queryString` or not. If, as you suggest, valueless parameters are not returned from `ParseQueryString` then you don't have to remove it, as it's already not there. If it is, removing it with the code you've provided should work.

Comment: @BartoszKP, valueless parameters are returned from `ParseQueryString`. I've updated the question text to show where the "traces" of it are left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the only way to remove the valueless qs parameter, which is actually considered by the query string parser a keyless value is to call the following:

```
if (queryString.GetValues(null).Contains("ncr"))
{
    queryString.Remove(null);
}
```

This will surely clear all the malformed qs paramters, but thus far I haven't found a batter way that works.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add a value to your query string if null and then remove it? I don't know why you would want to do this anyways but it is an option to accomplish what you want without string manipulation:

```
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(curUri.Query);

            if (queryString.GetValues(null).Contains("ncr"))
            {
                queryString.Add("ncr", "foo");
                queryString.Remove("ncr");
            }
```

Also, if you want to get the Request URL without the QueryString you can do this:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you think is the best way to rid the query string off of this parameter if it has played it's role and I need to redirect to the hame url, but without ncr?

Comment: Another thing - adding a value and then removing doesn't work for me =(. `Add.("ncr"...` adds another ncr that is then removed. The "phantom" one is retained after these operations.

Comment: for the cases where there is other stuff in QS, I am trying to come up with the way to remove just valueless ncr param.